# Regex Replace First Number from Phone number if it is a 1

Tags: replace, google-bigquery

I've got a list of phone numbers in bigquery.

Some have the number 1 in front and some do not. I would like to remove the 1s using regex replace:

The data looks as follows:

16047779887

4037778776

And I would like to return:

6047779887

4037778776

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select regex_replace(column_name, "1*", "")
from table
```

The * represents the rest of the string.

If the first letter is 1, remove it. (replace it with an empty string)